# Access to content of a process information

Tags: c#, process

I create an instance of IE with this code:

> System.Diagnostics.Process p =
>   System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE",
>   @"http://www.asnaf.ir/moreinfounit.php?sSdewfwo87kjLKH7624QAZMLLPIdyt75576rtffTfdef22de=1&iIkjkkewr782332ihdsfJHLKDSJKHWPQ397iuhdf87D3dffR=2009585&gGtkh87KJg89jhhJG75gjhu64HGKvuttt87guyr6e67JHGVt=117&cCli986gjdfJK755jh87KJ87hgf9871g00113kjJIZAEQ798=0a26e8ea07358781d128aa4bc98dd89a");

I want to get the contents of the opened window. Is it possible to read the HTML content by this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no. your processes run in different virtual addressing spaces. That would have been a serious security vulnerability if you could have read the memory space allocated by another process.

Edit: Consider using something like a WebBrowserControl in your original process. That way you cold easily retrieve the page it displays.

Answer (score 1):

Use following COde,

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://www.asnaf.ir/moreinfounit.php?sSdewfwo87kjLKH7624QAZMLLPIdyt75576rtffTfdef22de=1&iIkjkkewr782332ihdsfJHLKDSJKHWPQ397iuhdf87D3dffR=2009585&gGtkh87KJg89jhhJG75gjhu64HGKvuttt87guyr6e67JHGVt=117&cCli986gjdfJK755jh87KJ87hgf9871g00113kjJIZAEQ798=0a26e8ea07358781d128aa4bc98dd89a");
    // TODO: ur logice here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible, but I'd actually use a [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) to obtain the HTML content. If you really just want to get the HTML content for a given http-URL, using IE as a separate process is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: I use that but some information are displayed only when I request from a browser.

Comment: I need unit's address but nothing or english words for tempate are shown.

Comment: This information is most probably displayed through a JavaScript. You might call the site with a browser without JavaScript and then look at the source code of the page to see what they do to get this information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use WebClient class to retrieve web page content. Check this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx